# AVUrlAsset full resolution problems

Tags: ios, resolution, movie, avurlasset

I'm having a strange (for me) problem. I recorder two .mov file with my iphone 3gs. When I open them on mac they are 640x480. When I open in my app, with the standard calls for AVURLAsset, AVAssetReader and so on... I still get 480x360.

Could someone of you help (clarify) this? Is it normal? When I capture from camera I can run at 640x480 i.e. the CMSampleBuffer has right width and height, and so the UIImage I create farther.

```
AVURLAsset* asset;
NSString* fileBundle;
NSURL* url;
NSError* error;
NSArray* videoTracks;
AVAssetTrack* track;
NSMutableDictionary* dictionary;

fileBundle = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"TestMovies/movie1" ofType:@"mov"];
url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:fileBundle];

asset = [[AVURLAsset alloc] initWithURL:url options:nil];
movieAsset = [[AVAssetReader alloc] initWithAsset:asset error:&error];
videoTracks = [asset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
track = [videoTracks objectAtIndex:0];
dictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[dictionary setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA] forKey:(id)kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey];
movieOutput = [[AVAssetReaderTrackOutput alloc] initWithTrack:track outputSettings:dictionary];
[movieAsset addOutput:movieOutput];
[movieAsset startReading];
```

Then, in a timed member:

```
if( [movieAsset status] == AVAssetReaderStatusReading ) {
    CMSampleBufferRef buf;
    UIImage* img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCMSampleBufferRef:buf];
```

Obviously the extension to UIImage is included in the project...

Comment: Did you find out what was wrong? I'm having the same array out of bounds message, just using the buffer, without the img = ...